# Unity not Version Controlling Inspector Settings for GameObjects

Tags: git, github, unity-game-engine, inspector

I am working on a Unity project within a team and naturally, we use Github for version control.

Unfortunately we have a problem where inspector settings aren't being Version Controlled, this results in all of our GameObjects losing their outlets to Scripts and all connections are lost whenever we switch branches.

When working on something we would connect objects to scripts and get something like this:

[image: ShareViewInspectorConnected]

But then when we switch branches we get this, and have to reconnect everything:

[image: ShareViewInspectorDisconnected]

This is very annoying as the project continues to grow! 
We have two gitignore files, one at the root level of the project:

[image: RootLevelgitignore]

And one in `./Project`

[image: ProjectLevelgitignore]

There are others lying about, but I don't think they are effecting the Project folder (where the Unity project exists in) in any way..

I personally thought `Project/Library/assetDatabase3` was the file that stored the inspector settings, but I was wrong.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gitignore should not be ignoring meta files, they're vital to how unity functions.  A basic [Unity .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) file should only ignores `*.pidb.meta` and
`*.pdb.meta`.

Remove the `*.cs.meta` and `*.meta` entries.

Answer (score 1):

Inspector settings for scenes are stored in the scene asset file.

Are the scene asset files and scripts under git control.?

You should be able to see the changed files in git if you adjust the settings on one of your scenes.

Edit
The information about the script is stored in the ShareView.unity scene file.
e.g.

`m_Script: {fileID: 11500000, guid: e639a2fe330734500b135115fa275a75, type: 3}`

The guid referenced here should correspond with the script.meta file
e.g.

`fileFormatVersion: 2
guid: e639a2fe330734500b135115fa275a75`

I don't git control the asset database, or anything in /Library. When getting a commit change from another git user, unity reimports my assets (and from memory might recreate the .meta files). 
I wonder if some meta information that is being stored in the asset database file that is unique to your machine that is causing your issue.

Suggest you try removing the asset database file from git control

Edit.

Yes, don't git ignore the .meta files. Unity relies on them to tie things together

Comment: Is this the `ShareView.unity` file, or something else? When I change something in a scene the only files that change are `ShareView.unity` and `assetDatabase3`, which are both vc'd

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I previously added `assetDatabase3` as a possible solution to the problem but looks like it isn't one, so I'll reintroduce it in the gitignore. So you are saying I shouldn't be gitignoring the `ShareView.meta` files?